# Symfony4 - Undefined index: on entity join

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I'm getting an

> undefined index: order

error even though from what I can tell using [this documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html) I'm doing everything right.  Any ideas?

**OrdersRepository**

```
public function findByDateAndEmployee(\DateTime $date, int $employeeId)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->select('o')
        ->join('o.employees' ,'e')
        ->where('e.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id',$employeeId)
    ->getQuery()->getSql();
}
```

**Orders Entity**

```
class Orders
{
  ...
    /**
     * One Order has Many Employees.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Employee", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
     private $employees;
```

I know if I change the variable in "mappedBy" it will change the error message to whatever the variable name is, however when you see below "order" should be the mappedBy variable (at least, I think).

**OrderEmployees Entity**

```
class OrderEmployees
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $orderId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $employeeId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Orders", inversedBy="employees")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $order;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getOrderId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->orderId;
    }

    public function setOrderId(int $orderId): self
    {
        $this->orderId = $orderId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmployeeId(): ?int
    {
       return $this->employeeId;
    }

    public function setEmployeeId(int $employeeId): self
    {
       $this->employeeId = $employeeId;

       return $this;
    }

    public function getOrder(): Orders
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    public function setOrder(Orders $order): self
    {
        $this->order = $order;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `targetEntity="Employee"` to `targetEntity="OrderEmployees"` in your Orders entity should help.

From the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_manytoone):

> targetEntity: FQCN of the referenced target entity. Can be the
>   unqualified class name if both classes are in the same namespace.

Comment: Ahhh darn it I knew it happen to be something stupid like a typo.  Looked at that for like 30 minutes and it never even hit me lol.  Thanks a bunch!